# Differentiate between two different actions in loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, modulo

I am trying to do something like this

```
var teller = 1;
if (teller % 2 === 0) {
  "do this"
} else {
  "do something else"
}
teller++;
```

The problem is that he always comes into the else loop.
Someone knows why?

Comment: where is the loop...mentioned in your question title..??????

Comment: Have you tried teller % 2 == 0, so with two == instead of === ?

Comment: "else" is not a loop, it is part of a condition. A "loop" is something with "while" or  "for".

Comment: I found the answer. The problem was that "teller" is declared in my onclick event. This means that on a click the value always became 1.

Answer (score 2):

because `1 % 2 === 0` returns `false`

you might want to put it inside a loop

```
var teller = 1;
while(teller < 100){ //100 is the range, just a sample
    if (teller % 2 === 0) {
         "do this"
    } else {
          "do something else"
    }
    teller++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stepping through your code:

```
var teller = 1;          //teller is now 1
if (teller % 2 === 0) {  //1 % 2 === 1, so this statement is skipped
  "do this"
} else {                 //since the if statement was skipped, this gets run
  "do something else"
}
teller++;                //this has no affect on the above
```

If you want to put this in a loop, see @DryrandzFamador's answer.